# Web requests suddenly not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

My app makes calls to my api like so:

```
Debug.WriteLine ("Making an API request: " + action);
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/api/"+ action");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";
string content = "d";

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

return content;
```

And this has been working perfectly for a few months. Suddenly one day my app is no longer working. Debugging i'm finding the requests are either timing out or throwing the error:

```
 (System.Net.WebException) Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure
```

What does that error mean? And why did it suddenly start? This code hasn't been changed since the release of the app. The request works perfectly when typed into a browser.

Comment: may be related to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10888

Comment: @Jason hmm it worked for about a month though... and then suddenly it stops working everywhere..

Comment: Did you change anything in Google Webmaster tools, or anything involving url canonicalization?
In your browser, when you type in the url does it now include the www?

Can you cast the WebException to an HttpWebException and get the results from that?

Comment: @Prospector I didn't change anything on the website, but including `www` seems to have fixed the issue! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `www.` to all the urls fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This exception resulted from a connection timeout. Probable causes are that the service provided by http://domain.com/api/"+ action is no longer available, temporarily unavailable, or your internet connection is down.

Comment: As I said `The request works perfectly when typed into a browser.` Ive tried on multiple phones in multiple places and connections.

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? The phone seems to be blocking this type of request.

Comment: No I havent figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `HTTPWebRequest`'s proxy settings like:

```cs
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
// request.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

I had similar exception (but when downloading images, not calling remote method) and it helped.